# Get the one value from array if it repeated again and again

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
 <?php print_r($disease); ?>

  Array ( [0] => Array ( [disease_name] => magraines ) [1] => Array ( 
[disease_name] => magraines ) [2] => Array ( [disease_name] => magraines ) 
[3] => Array ( [disease_name] => magraines ) [4] => Array ( [disease_name] 
=> magraines ) [5] => Array ( [disease_name] => brain cancer ) [6] => Array 
( [disease_name] => brain cancer ) )
```

I want to get one value magraines and brain cancer...not again and again

```
<?php foreach ($disease as $get_disease)
{
  echo $get_disease['disease_name'];
} 
?>
```

Here is the text:

> magrainesmagrainesmagrainesmagrainesmagraines

I want just get one **magraines** and **braincancer**.

Comment: Spelling: I think you mean "migraines".

Comment: Your text sample indicates that a disease might appear in a string, repeated several times. However, your array above that shows that they would be in different array indexes. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php **array_unique** function

According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array

**Updated**

According to documentation:

> array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

But you can use the below code:

**Code**

```
$unique_disease = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $disease)));

foreach ($unique_disease as $get_disease)
{
    echo $get_disease['disease_name'];
}
```

Comment: @NadirAlyani Ok wait.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$new_arr=array_unique(array_column($disease, 'disease_name'));
print_r($new_arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => magraines
    [5] => brain cancer
)
```